# how to show checked unchecked in multiple checkbox laravel edit blade view

Tags: php, laravel

edit blade view :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('user/rencana-kerjasama/edit')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
{{ csrf_field() }} 
 <div class='col-md-6'>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bidang[]"  value="Pendidikan" {{ (is_array(old('bidang')) and in_array('Pendidikan', old('bidang'))) ? ' checked' : '' }}>Pendidikan
 </label>
  </div>
<div class="checkbox">
 <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="bidang[]" value="Penelitian" > Penelitian
 </label>
</div>
 <div class="checkbox">
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bidang[]"  value="Pengabdian Masyarakat"> Pengabdian Masyarakat
 </label>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

controller :

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $title = $this->title;
        $data = RencanaKerjasama::find($id);
        return view('user.' . $title . '.edit', compact('title', 'data', 'checked'));
    }
```

how to show if checkbox is checked or unchecked in view?

i use this but not work

```
{{ (is_array(old('bidang')) and in_array('Penelitian', old('bidang'))) ? ' checked' : '' }}
```

array value when i try dd($data)   :

```
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "bidang" => "Pendidikan,Pengabdian Masyarakat,"
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@if(is_array(old('bidang')) && in_array('Pendidikan', old('bidang'))){{"checked='checked'"}}@endif
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bidang[]"  value="Pendidikan" @if(is_array(old('bidang')) && in_array('Pendidikan', old('bidang'))){{"checked='checked'"}}@endif>Pendidikan
 </label>
  </div>
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
$array = [
 "id" => 3,
 "bidang" => "Pendidikan,Pengabdian Masyarakat,",
 "created_at" => null,
 "updated_at" => null,
 ];

 $bidang = explode(',',$array['bidang']);

 if(in_array('Pendidikan', $bidang)){ 
     echo "something";
     }
```

**[DEMO](https://paiza.io/projects/Uo6SPVCcYHw6tu0FECnTqg)**

Comment: i try use this `@if(is_array(old('bidang')) && in_array('Penelitian', old('bidang'))){{"checked='checked'"}}@endif ` but not work

Comment: @ipibk check your condition proper is working or not.

Comment: where I check the conditions?

Comment: @ipibk before html like `<?php if(is_array(old('bidang')) && in_array('Penelitian', old('bidang'))){ echo "something" } ?>`

Comment: @ipibk See Edited answer. change value in condition to `Pendidikan`

Comment: still the same..not working..is there anything I have to change in the controller?

Comment: @ipibk print_r(old('bidang')) array and output include in question.

Comment: @ipibk See Edited Answer `Example` and try like that way by `explode`

Comment: i follow Example but nothing show..and if try   `{{var_dump(in_array('Pendidikan', $bidang))}}` the result is **bool(false)**

Comment: @ipibk Check Demo here https://paiza.io/projects/Uo6SPVCcYHw6tu0FECnTqg

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bidang[]"  value="Pendidikan" 
      {{ in_array('Pendidikan', old('bidang')) ? 
     "checked" : '' }} >Pendidikan
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

$hobby = explode(', ', $data->hobby);

<input class="form-control" name="hobby[]" type="checkbox" value="cricket" >